# How to pass extra parameter to mail function from magento

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, php, smtp, send-mail

I want to send extra parameter to  `mail` function in  magento. I didn't find any raw `mail` function in magento, can any one help me where I will get that function.

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers, 'Iwantopassthis@test.com'); // I want to pass 5th parameter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you magento is using sendmail to send an email, you can find the `mail()` function in `Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail`. Check the method `public function _sendMail()`.

You can find this file in `lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php` of your magento 1 root and `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Se‌​ndmail.php` in your magento2 root. Also it is not recommended to edit this file directly. If you want to modify this, copy this file to `app/code/local/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php` (there won't such directories by default but you can create) and then modify the method `_sendMail()`;

Comment: Where we can find `Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail`  class

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you!. @Nidheesh.  Magento 2 We can find the function here `vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php`

Answer (score 0):

> The **additional_parameters** parameter can be used to pass an additional
>   parameter.

```
<?php
mail('nobody@example.com', 'the subject', 'the message', null,
   '-fwebmaster@example.com');
?>
```

For more detail [additional-parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)